# How to destroy current session but not other session

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a simple log in system where there are 2 type of user (role: 0,1). If user is role 0 then user is redirected to search.php, else role is 1,redirected to overview.php.

```
if ($role == 0){
  session_regenerate_id();
  $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
  $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['email'];
  $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
  header('Location: search.php');
} elseif ($role == 1) {
  session_regenerate_id();
  $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
  $_SESSION['user'] = $name;
  $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['email'];
  $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
  header('Location: overview.php');
}
```

I am able to logout and destroy session, but if both user are logged in and one user logout it will end session for both user.
Here is my logout.php:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Destroy the session.
session_destroy();

header('Location: login.php');
exit;
?>
```

Then I found this solution [source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php). I was not sure how to get to_destroy_id ($des) so I set it to current session id.
Here is my updated logout.php:

```
<?php
$des = session_id();
// 1. commit session if it's started.
if (session_id()) {
    session_commit();
}

// 2. store current session id
session_start();
$current_session_id = session_id();
session_commit();

// 3. hijack then destroy session specified.
session_id($des);
session_start();
session_destroy();
session_commit();

// 4. restore current session id. If don't restore it, your current session will refer to the session you just destroyed!
session_id($current_session_id);
session_start();
session_commit();
// Redirect to the login page:
header('Location: restTablet.php');

?>
```

This worked for first time then it stopped working again. Everyone logout if one user logout.
I would just like to destroy user session if they clicked logout, and other users stays logged in. Any idea how can I implement this?

UPDATE: making the following change to logout.php I was able to keep other logged in if one user logout, but once the user logout and tries to go back user is able to access it again without loggin. Here is the logout.php:

```
<?php
$des = session_id();
// 1. commit session if it's started.
if (session_id()) {
    session_commit();
}

// 2. store current session id
session_start();
$current_session_id = session_id();
session_commit();

// 3. hijack then destroy session specified.
session_id($des);
session_start();
session_destroy();
session_commit();

// Redirect to the login page:
header('Location: gabLogin.php');
?>
```

Comment: Where is stored `$role` value ?

Comment: Logging out 1 user should not affect other users, of course. Are you sure about that?  How do you see that problem, I mean describe how you see it. What is your session storage and config?

Comment: Role is stored in sql database.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest your $_SESSION data in a parent level.
For example you have two roles, `role 1` and `role 2`. 
Set `$_SESSION` like the following:

```php
if ($role == 0){
  session_regenerate_id();
  $_SESSION['role_0']['loggedin'] = TRUE;
  $_SESSION['role_0']['name'] = $_POST['email'];
  $_SESSION['role_0']['id'] = $id;
  header('Location: search.php');
} elseif ($role == 1) {
  session_regenerate_id();
  $_SESSION['role_1']['loggedin'] = TRUE;
  $_SESSION['role_1']['user'] = $name;
  $_SESSION['role_1']['name'] = $_POST['email'];
  $_SESSION['role_1']['id'] = $id;
  header('Location: overview.php');
}
```

Then when your user logs out of say `role_0`, unset only the parent session value for that role.

```php
//use logic in logout form to POST proper logout for that role.
if(isset($_POST['logout_0'])){ //--> role_0 is logging out
  unset($_SESSION['role_0']); //--> all child data for role_0 should be unset now.
  //--> check if user is logged in as alternate role
  if($_SESSION['role_1']['loggedin'] === TRUE){
    header('Location: overview.php');
  }else{
    //--> redirect to the page you wish them to go to when logged out
  }
}
```

Comment: this is not the perfect way to handle login session